# file object methods throws NullPointerException - Google Drive API

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, google-drive-api

After configure and successfully test quickstart code in https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java

I'm receiving NullPointerException after trying other file methods e.g.: getFileExtension(), get WebViewLink(), get Md5 Checksum() even when file.getName() and file.getId() works fine.

Original working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = getDriveService();

    // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
    FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
         .execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

I'll appreciate any help to understand Null Pointer reason calling other methods on file objects.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this the actual code that's giving you an NPE?  Or something different?  If this is not the actual code, then please show it to us, as it's rather hard to find the error in code we can't see.

Comment: David, that code is part of first link (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java)

Comment: So where's the actual code that gives you the error?  I can't help you find an error, if you don't show me the code that has the error.

Comment: Ok, for example, I want web view link for 'file', then I execute: file.get WebViewLink(), that give me NullPointer. Shakhar told me that I need to set fields but FileList result2 =service.files().list() .setFields("nextPageToken, files(" + file.getId() + ", " + file.getName() + ")").execute(); is giving me com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseExce‌​ption: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Well, good that you found the answer.  But in future, it's best if you put the failing code into the question, rather than burying it in a comment two hours later.  You have made it difficult for anyone to help you, and Shakhar has done extremely well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the fields you need in `.setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")`. Right now, you just have `id` and `name`. So, you are getting a partial response having just the `id` and `name` and so everything else is `null` and therefore you are getting `NullPointerException`. If you want to get the full response containing all data about the files, try `.setFields("nextPageToken, files")`.

Comment: Shakhar, this is giving me com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request: 

FileList result2 =service.files().list()
               .setFields("nextPageToken, files(" + file.getId() + ", " + file.getName() + ")").execute();

Comment: @AER I just updated the answer to give an easy solution. I just tried it myself and it works if you use just "files" instead of using "files(id, name)" in your original code.